# Why is $(-\infty, \sqrt{2}) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ open in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am looking at an example of disconnected spaces.

> Let $U=(-\infty, \sqrt{2})\cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $V=(\sqrt{2},\infty) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. Then $U,V$ are open in $\mathbb{Q}$ by definition of the subspace topology...

From my understanding of subspace topology, I thought it's the subsets of (in this case) $U,V$ that are "intersections" of the open sets in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Well, I don't know *what* topology is defined on $\mathbb{Q}$ here.

Say $U$ is essentially the set of rationals that are less than $\sqrt{2}$. If $U$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$ that means "the rationals less than $\sqrt{2}$ are in the topology of $\mathbb{Q}$." Yes?

Unless the topology is a discrete topology on $\mathbb{Q}$ I don't see how $U,V$ can be irrefutably open in the rationals.

Are we supposed to just assume there's a discrete topology on $\mathbb{Q}$ unless stated otherwise explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is virtually no situation in which you want to consider the discrete topology on $\Bbb Q$.

First, what's meant here is the subspace topology on $\Bbb Q$, considering $\Bbb Q$ as sitting inside the real numbers $\Bbb R$. The open sets in the reals are unions of intervals; in particular, $(-\infty,\sqrt 2)$ is open in $\Bbb R$. Then (definition of subspace topology) $(-\infty,\sqrt 2) \cap \Bbb Q$ is open in $\Bbb Q$.

More straightforward than the above fancy name, though, is that the topology on $\Bbb Q$ is given by the metric $d(p,q) = |p-q|$. (This is the same metric as on the reals; but here, $p$ and $q$ are rationals.) This topology is far from discrete! If it were discrete, then you couldn't find rationals arbitrarily close to, say, $0$. But $a_n = 1/n$ gets arbitrarily close to zero.

Comment: Hi, so to check if my understanding is right; it seems like you're saying that $\mathbb{R}$ has the Euclidean topology, yes? And therefore $(-\infty,\sqrt{2})$ is open in the reals. And here, clearly $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$ so we take *the rationals* as the subset of the reals. In which, we can thus define a subspace topology *on the rationals* which is basically(by definition of subspace topology), intersection with all open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ with subset $\mathbb{Q}$. i.e. $(-\infty, \sqrt{2}) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is one of such intersections hence open(in $\mathbb{Q}$). Correct?

Comment: @JohnTrail That's correct.